# How to handle the case where the axios response comes after the component is rendered?

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios

I am creating a blog application in rest framework and reactjs. On the home page, under componentDidMount, I send an API call using axios to get all the articles and setState of articles to the return. As I have studied, axios works on the idea of promise such that the code doesnt proceed, if the API is not fetched for a particular component. Please tell me, if I am wrong.

Then, I send a GET call to get the writer's name, who wrote the article by the id. Though, I assumed that the axios works as a promise. But, it doesnt work that way. Now, I am not sure how to move ahead.

Here is a snippet. So, in `mainBody.js`, I make the api call as:

```
class MainBody extends Component {
state = {};

componentDidMount () {
    this.get_all_articles();
  };

get_writer_name (id) {
    let authstr = 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.token;
    let writer_url = "http://localhost:8000/api/writer/" + id.toString() + "/";
    axios.get(writer_url, { headers: { Authorization: authstr }})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data['name'])
        return response.data['name'];
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Got error")
      })
  };

get_all_articles () {
    let authstr = 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.token;
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/articles/", { headers: { Authorization: authstr }})
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({articles: response.data});
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Got error")
      })
  }

render () {
return (
{this.state.articles.map((article, key) =>
                          <ArticleView key={article.id} article={article} writer_name={this.get_writer_name(article.created_by)} />
                        )}
)
}
}
```

In articleview2, I print all the data that is present in each of the articles along with the writer's name.

My articleview class is:

```
class ArticleView extends Component {
state = {article: this.props.article};
componentDidMount() {
console.log(this.props.writer_name;
}
render () {
return (
<React.Fragment>
<h2>{article.title}</h2>
<p>{article.body}</p>
<span>{this.props.writer_name}</span>
</React.Fragment>
)
}
}
```

If you see closely, I wrote two console.log statements to get the writer names. Based on the order, first the console log present in articleview class runs, which is undefined, and thenafter the data is fetched from the API call and the console log runs which returns the correct writer name.

I wanted to know, where is the error? Also, as I noticed, there are too many API calls being made to get the writer's name multiple time for all the listed articles. What are the industry best practices for these cases?

Comment: use a loader, `state = { isLoading: true }` when you get the data from api set it to false. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/movie-api?file=AdditionalInfo.js

Comment: Is the structure of your api fixed? If not it maybe better to have the get_all_articles also return the writer name, the less calls you do the better.  In your render, you're always best off checking type and length of the array before trying to use it `{articles !== undefined && articles.length > 0 ? Do map : ''}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know where is the error.

When you are writing `this.state.articles.map()`, means you're using property map of the `Array` articles which may be undefined before the data is fetched that will cause you the error `Cannot read property map of undefined`.

> Solution

Now, as the API request is asynchronous, means render method will not wait for the data to come. So what you can do is use a loader variable in the state, and set it to true as long as the request is being made, and when the response has come, make it false, and show the loader in render when this.state.loader is true, and show articles when it is false.
Or you can initialize this.state.articles with an empty array that won't cause you the error.

> Also, as I noticed, there are too many API calls being made to get the writer's name multiple time for all the listed articles. What are the industry best practices for these cases?

It is extremely bad practice to make an API request in the loop. Even myself has been scolded on it once I did it in my company.

> Solution

You have tell your backend engineer to provide you filter for including the writer's name in each object of the article. We use [Loopback](https://loopback.io/) on our backend, which provides a filter for including the related model in each object internally.

Comment: A comment on downvote is appreciated to make my answer better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your API calls have a lot of things in common, you should first set up an axios instance that re-uses those common features:

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/',
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}` }
});
```

Now since your `MainBody` needs to fetch the resources from the API asynchronously, there will be a short period where the data is not yet available. There are two ways you can handle this. Either the `MainBody` can be responsible for making all the calls, or it can be responsible for just making the call to get all the articles, then each of the `ArticleView` components can be responsible for getting the writer's name. I'll demonstrate the first approach below:

```
class MainBody extends Component {
  state = { articles: null, error: null, isLoading: true };

  async componentDidMount () {
    try {
      const response = await api.get('articles/');
      const articles = await Promise.all(
        response.data.map(async article => {
          const response = await api.get(`writer/${article.created_by}/`);
          return { ...article, writer_name: response.data.name };
        })
      );

      this.setState({ articles, isLoading: false });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error, isLoading: false });
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { articles, error, isLoading } = this.state;

    return isLoading ? 'Loading...' : error
      ? `Error ${error.message}`
      : articles.map(article => (
        <ArticleView
          key={article.id}
          article={article}
          writer_name={article.writer_name}
        />
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, why did you use async in componentDidMount as you are already waiting for the data to load via isLoading flag, right?

Comment: @Phoenix I use `async` in order to use the `await` keyword and unwrap the promises returned by axios...